# excel countifs with AND & OR

Tags: excel, countif, array-formulas

I'm trying to create an Excel function that counts instances that meet 3 criteria. For example data in [sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii0zB.jpg), I want to:

1)For each type of 'Structure' count number of rows in which
2)'Horizontal' is greater than zero, OR
3)'Vertical' is greater than zero

Expected result for example data in column D.

An array formula of the type

=SUM(IF(($B$2:$B$7>0)+($C$2:$C$7>0),1,0))

counts in accordance with criteria 2) and 3) but does not group by 'Structure'.

Any thoughts?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(($A$2:$A$7= A2)*(($B$2:$B$7>0)+($C$2:$C$7>0)),1,0))
```

Remember to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

The `*` is used for `And` and the `+` for `Or`.  So this will pick up only those that have `Structure` in column A and has a greater than 0 in one or both of column B or column C

Comment: Many thanks Scott. Simple and logical. Works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** following comment by Scott Cranger

If `F2` contains the Structure type, then:

```
G2: =SUMPRODUCT(--((Structure_Type=F2)*((Horizontal>0)+(Vertical>0))>0))
```

where Structure_Type, Horizontal, and Vertical are the ranges containing those elements.  This formula is normally entered.